# Initialize an empty value for number type in react

Tags: reactjs, graphql, graphql-js

I'm working on a workout logger for logging sets for exercises a user performs. It asks users to select an exercise from a `select`, as well as the amount of weight and reps they did for the set. Weights and sets will be stored as type `number`. I am using React on the frontend and GraphQL on the backend.

Can I initialize these values as an 'empty' number, where the input field is left blank but still recognizes that the type for these fields should be of `number`. Currently, I have them set as undefined and all works but in the console I get this warning message `onSubmit`, which is where my question stems from:

```
Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.
```

```
const initialState = {
  exerciseName: "",
  weight: undefined,
  reps: undefined,
  notes: "",
};
```

I can set the initial values as 0 and it works but I don't want to allow users to submit the form if they forget to change these initial values. Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I have also tried to just keep them as empty strings, but then this crashes the react app with an error upon submission of the form, as the backend expects the values to be of `Float` and `Int` types.

Comment: Setting it as null instead of undefined would not help?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it works the same as undefined but adds an extra warning message on top of the other one.

Comment: You can try make a minimal reproducible example in codesandbox, there is not much information on the post... (or you can just put some reasonable defaults on the fields, for example 0, and then set some validation that checks if the field is 0 and displays some error message before sending it to the backend)

Comment: I will do so now, but I believe there will be alot of files as I would need to include the backend code as well, which is why I did not in the first place.

Comment: @JLI_98 well it **is** a warning, not an error, but if you want to get rid of it why not set it to 0 and prevent the form from submitting if the reps or weight is 0. Doesn't make sense to allow them to submit anyway if either of those values are 0, so just disable form submission if that's the csae

Comment: @Jayce444 I understand where you're coming from, but there are some exercises where some might not use any weight at all (body weight exercises such as dips or pulls ups) and some may want to log sets where they failed to do the weight.

Comment: it doesn't matter ... still a kind of validation rule/condition ... **just don't send all state as variables when it is not required** for some type of exercises - this way you don't need undefined initial value ... use only required values, validate them before mutation ... block when arg is required but it's value is out of valid range, not touched, etc... use formik?